# Docker on windows with broken bios

Tags: windows, docker, virtualization, bios

I've wanted to install docker on my windows. I'm getting an error. `Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See` . I can't go to my bios, after pressing f2 i have just a black screen, i tried to restart my computer manually and from windows in advanced settings from tutorials. In task manager my virtualization is off, I checked my Cpu supports virtualization on `Intel Processor Identification Utility` and it is. My Cpu is `i7 4770k 3,5Ghz`. I downloaded bios update for my motherboard but I know, I have to put it on my Pendrive and open it from my bios, couldn't install it straight from my pc with `.CAP` extension. My motherboard is `Asus Z97M-PLUS`. I tried to set my virtualization without bios with tutorials, PowerShell commands, changing settings, avast, hyperV. Can't describe exactly what I was doing and which commands I was putting in because I tried everything I found.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help you in this case as this is a very case-specific problem, especially hardware specific. The fact that you can't enter your bios will make enabling virtualization very difficult, as this switch must be switched there, and only there. I suppose you could try resetting your BIOS by shorting two pins / pressing a button on your motherboard, to see if that makes it want to open again.

Try [this motherboard manual document](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/Z97M-PLUS/E9678_z97m-plus_guide_V2_web_only.pdf) at section 1.2.6 and 1.2.7 depending on your use case.

Furthermore, this website probably is not the best place to ask these sort of questions, and tech forums would probably be better able to help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried to remove the batterry from MB and clear the jumper. But both methods don't work. For now, seems like docker have to wait.